# Ler ficheiro do fim para o inicio

Tags: c, arquivo

```
....
         fseek(arq, 0, SEEK_END);
                while(!feof(arq)){
                    //fgets(&ch,2,arq);
                    fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, arq);
                    //printf("\n%c",ch);
                    num = atoi(&ch);
                    vem=makenode();
                    vem->numero=num;
                    lista=insertfirst(lista,vem);
                }
```

....

Como faço para ler do fim do ficheiro para o inicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que conste, vejo isso como algo meramente engraçado e sem aplicação real, não obstante, consegue faze-lo servindo-se de [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/?kw=fseek) e [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/).

Começa por se posicionar no fim com `fseek` e com `ftell` descobre a posição desse fim. Depois vai diminuindo a posição manualmente e utiliza novamente `fseek` para ler desse byte:

```
int main(){
    FILE *arq = fopen("teste.txt","r");
    fseek(arq, 0, SEEK_END); //ir para o fim do arquivo
    long posicao = ftell(arq); //assumir a posição como fim
    char ch;

    while(posicao >= 0){
        fseek(arq, posicao, SEEK_SET); //reposicionar de acordo com a posicao
        fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, arq); //ler o caratere
        printf("%c\n",ch);
        posicao--; //andar uma posição para trás
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A instrução em foco é:

```
fseek(arq, posicao, SEEK_SET); // arquivo, offset, tipo de posicionamento
```

`SEEK_SET` significa posicionamento pelo inicio. No caso irá ser posicionado `posicao` bytes a partir do inicio. Como `posicao` vai diminuindo de `1` em `1` no `while`, vai se posicionando cada vez mais para o inicio.

Uma solução mais performatica passa por ler o arquivo todo (do inicio para o fim) para um `char[]` e depois utilizar esse array de trás para a frente, o que evita ter de fazer vários `fseek`s.